# View a WPF UserControl on another computer over LAN

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics

I have a UserControl (inherits Canvas) on a WPF Window that is reading and displaying some realtime imagery, and overlaying shapes and text atop the image.

I'm looking for ways to clone this Canvas onto another WPF Window on another computer. The host computer has a bunch of controls that affect the programs operation, I want the client to be view-only, and just that Canvas -- so VNC/RDP/etc aren't options for me.

An interval-based refresh would be fine. I'm looking for high-level suggestions, I'll figure out (or ask SO) the implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

How about serializing to XAML with a timer and sending this over WCF? I know there are (used to be?) soe limitations with the XAML serializer, namely it didn't remember event bindings AFAIK. This would only matter if your view was interactive I suppose?

My $0.02

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you want to transfer UI elements. Transfer the data that represents them and use the same renderer on both ends to render the data to the client. If you're using MVVM properly, this is a very easy thing to do.